# Can I choose a pos.model in Stanford parser?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to use gate-EN-twitter.model for pos tagging when in the process of parsing by Stanford parser. Is there an option on command line that does that? like `-pos.model gate-EN-twitter.model`? Or do I have to use Stanford pos tagger with gate model for tagging first then use its output as input for the parser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to force the Stanford Parser to use the tags generated by this Twitter-specific POS tagger. That's definitely possible, though this tweet from Stanford NLP about this exact model should serve as a warning:

> **Tweet from Stanford NLP, 13 Apr 2014:**
>
> Using CoreNLP on social media? Try GATE Twitter model **(iff not parsing…)** `-pos.model gate-EN-twitter.model` https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/twitter-postagger.html #nlproc
>
> (https://twitter.com/stanfordnlp/status/455409761492549632)

That being said, if you really want to try, we can't stop you :)

There is a [parser FAQ entry](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#f) on forcing in your own tags. See http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#f

Basically, you have two options (see the FAQ for full details):

- If calling the parser from the command line, you can pre-tag your text file and then alert the parser to the fact that the text is pre-tagged using some command-line options.
- If parsing programmatically, the `LexicalizedParser#parse` method will accept any `List<? extends HasTag>` and treat the tags in that list as golden. Just pre-tag your list (using the CoreNLP pipeline or `MaxentTagger`) and pass on that token list to the parser.

Comment: Thanks so much! I used twitie pos tagger and generated some pos tagged input, and used LexicalizedParser to generate a .tree file (with `penn` as outputFormat). I wanted to generate a conll formatted output with `java -mx5g -cp "stanford-parser-full-2014-10-31/*:" edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure -treeFile output.tree -conllx >output_conllx.txt`

Comment: But it seems it cannot find some of the twitter specific pos tags that generated by twitie, such CD. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No head rule defined for CD using class edu.stanford.nlp.trees.SemanticHeadFinder in CD-46`

Comment: Hmm.. CD is a normal Penn Treebank POS tag, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks. Dunno why it gives an error there. But I'm guessing it will not work with `edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure` as twitie pos tags do contain twitter specifics like HT for hashtag...

Comment: Right. This is probably why the Stanford NLP tweet was explicitly against using this for parsing.

Comment: Thanks so much! I now have some already tokenized text (by using a different tokenizer) and i used `java -mx5g -cp "stanford-parser-full-2014-10-31/*:" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -sentences newline -tokenized -escaper edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBEscapingProcessor -outputFormat "penn" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.caseless.ser.gz input.txt > output.txt` for parsing. Can I select which pos model to use with this command? If not which pos tagger does it use with this parsing model? Thanks again!

Comment: You need to pre-tag the text. You can use the Stanford Tagger to do this, and output a file with PTB-style tagging indicators. Full details (including what command line invocation to use once you have the content pre-tagged) are in the FAQ here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#f

Comment: I tried Stanford pos tagger then Stanford parser (with all necessary commands) for a conllx output file as mentioned in the earlier comment. But it keeps giving the `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No head rule defined for...` exception. The Stanford parser did give me a valid conllx output from a pre-tokenized but not-yet-tagged input, but i wonder which pos model did it use for the tagging?

Comment: Yep, it's not possible to use this tagset with the parser if it does not match the standard PTB tagset. This exception comes because the head finder (a tool used to extract useful linguistic information from trees) doesn't recognize some tag that you've provided.